# What do these quarter notes without a stem represent?

Tags: sheet-music, rhythm

I was playing a piece recently and came across this:
[image: Four quarter notes, without stems]

What are these called, and are they any different from your typical quarter notes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The box indicates to improvise on the notes within it. The pseudo-Italian word 'glitterando' tells you to create a glittering effect, a sort of tremolo effect using the four notes. The wavy line extending to the right shows you how long to continue this.

Comment: @BlueHerring In other words, much like what the right hand is doing, but with four pitches instead of two.

Comment: Didn't know that existed. My fingers certainly aren't fast enough for that.

Comment: @AndyBonner Not exactly. The tremolo usually has a constant frequency, which may be determined based on the cuts (or "as fast as possible" when not possible otherwise); also, while obviously a 2 note tremolo doesn't give much choice, it should always be intended as alternation: this is important for tremolos indicating 2 groups of notes. In this case, instead, there is complete freedom in choosing which notes to play (for instance, b d b f d b f d, etc.) and unless a more specific explanation is provided, some level of freedom in rhythm is usually implied.

Comment: Note: "glitterando" is not an Italian word :-) "Verbing" (making a verb from any noun) is not possible in Italian language, even though it's sometimes acceptable with loanwords, when they have become common enough and no existing Italian word/verb exists. "Glitterato" (adjective) has been recognized by some dictionaries, but the verb "Glitterare" and its conjugations (like the gerund form using the -ando suffix) is not considered grammatically correct yet. It may be used colloquially, but I wouldn't suggest it for a musical score; if Italian terms are preferred for some reason, then a *real* »

Comment: » Italian word should be chosen instead. I've seen this in the past, but I don't really remember the specific terms they used. Possible alternatives I could think of: scintillando, luccicando, or even more verbose descriptions such as "ad lib, scintillando [come fosse glitter]".

Comment: @musicamante Googling "glitterando" yields evidence that it's occasionally used, mostly in the form of Reddit questions much like the one at hand asking "what is this?"

Comment: @AndyBonner I've only seen [one occurrence](//www.reddit.com/r/pianolearning/comments/l11yt4/help_whats_a_glitterando/) "relevant" for music on reddit, and seeing the context (for instance, the font used for the "meno [mosso?]") I wouldn't consider it as a canonically acceptable reference. While "glitterato" is recognized, the verb is not (yet!), and it's mostly used in visual fields where "glitter" *is* a technical term and usage of such *verbing* is much more permissive than *written music*. I'm not saying it's a huge error to write it, but since: 1. there's no "glitter" in music; »

Comment: @AndyBonner » 2. using such loanwords should only be acceptable wherever no Italian alternative exists; 3. alternatives *do* exist in proper Italian language; then I wouldn't suggest its usage: as said, it's *not* an Italian word, no matter if most people would be able to understand it; maybe, someday it will be, but an understandable made-up word doesn't make it right. If the composer/copyist/editor are Italian, they should better know that. If they are not, then they should avoid making up words in a language they only partially know just for the sake of "Italian style in written music".

Comment: @musicamante I had a feeling the word was not really Italian even though I found several references to it on the net. The English 'glittering' would have been better, but even with the pseudo-Italian the meaning is clear.